# Unable to process Jar entry [org/apache/juli/AsyncFileHandler$LogEntry.class] java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: maven, cxf, pom.xml, web.xml, catalina

I'm testing a WS SOAP with apache CXF (java 7 )and I 'm having this error, I deleted this jar I thought maybe it's corrupt and maven build again but I am having same result, Can anybody explain me this "ZIP" Exception
this is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebService</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <cxf.version>2.7.3</cxf.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ant</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
      <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-es</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-fr</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-ja</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.57</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

the stack:

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/apache/juli/AsyncFileHandler$LogEntry.class] from Jar [jar:file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp15/wtpwebapps/WebService/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-juli-7.0.57.jar!/] for annotations
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.fillNew(FastDataInputStream.java:194)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readInt(FastDataInputStream.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deleting all files in the repository and clean and build again solved it